# Attempting to install and run Flask but I keep receiving an error message

Tags: python, flask

I appreciate anyone who's willing to try and help me solve this problem. I'm currently taking a Machine Learning course and I've already failed at trying to figure what should be a simple install. I will try and explain the best I can but please be patient as I'm a novice.

I'm using Terminal to run a very basic Flask application. In the terminal I was able to install Flask. I typed these two commands in the terminal:

1. export FLASK_APP=hello.py
2. flask run

After running flask I now have an error message preventing me from going further: 
"Error: Could not import "hello".

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Above is the code I am using in Sublime that is supposed to allow for the return of "Hello, World!"

The command is supposed to run on a URL address but instead it just tells me that it won't import "hello". hello.py is the Sublime save file that has the code on it.

I apologize if it sounds confusing because I am entirely confused and don't even really know how to word my problem properly. If anyone can help me I'll try and provide as much information as I can but the Machine Learning course I'm taking is the Siraj Raval one if anyone is familiar with it. It's literally the 2nd video in the introduction so as you can imagine I feel very frustrated at the fact that I'm already having serious issues in trying to understand this. Thank you for reading and any help is very much appreciated!

Here is the exact sequence of command prompts I used if this helps >>

```
Last login: Sun Sep 22 17:25:19 on ttys000
Justins-MacBook-Pro:~ justinunion$ mkdir myproject
mkdir: myproject: File exists
Justins-MacBook-Pro:~ justinunion$ cd myproject/
Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$ python3 -m venv venv
Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$ pip3 install flask
Requirement already satisfied: flask in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask) (1.1.1)
(venv) Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$ sublime
-bash: sublime: command not found
(venv) Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$ ls
venv
(venv) Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$ sublime hello.py
-bash: sublime: command not found
(venv) Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$ ls
venv
(venv) Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
(venv) Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "hello.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not import "hello".
(venv) Justins-MacBook-Pro:myproject justinunion$
```

Comment: What directory is `hello.py` in, what directory are you in when you type `flask run`, and what is your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Show the output of the `tree` command to give us a sense of what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for replying and I appreciate your patience. I'm very new to this so I'm not sure what directory I'm in or what the PYTHONPATH is. I'm using Python 3 and I've edited my post to include the command line that was used. I hope this helps.

Comment: you must be in the same directory as `hello.py` otherwise python will not found it. PYTHONPATH is an environment variable that contains a list of paths where python will search for modules

Comment: @Justin go to terminal, type `ls` and see the contents of the folder, there should be a hello.py file. If not; copy the hello.py file and store it in your current working directory which can be found with command `pwd`

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much I was able to figure it out with your help. The issue was that hello.py was actually saved onto Desktop/iCloud. I ended up doing what anon told me and typed the ls in terminal. I realized I only had venv, so after I entered the pwd in terminal I was able to find the working directory and I saved hello.py to users --> myproject. After that I ran flask and it worked. I appreciate the quick response and now I'm motivated and excited to continue. Thanks again!